# XOR with values

Tags: java, refactoring, xor

I want to check if **`a`** is equal to a value, and **`b`** is equal to another, or vice versa

For example

```
(a == 3 && b == 5) || (a == 5 && b == 3)
```

I know if it was `boolean` variables, I could just XOR them. How can I achieve the same function when checking for two values?

Comment: `if (a+b == 8 && Math.abs(a-b) == 2)`

Comment: There can be many tricks to mimic this condition, some more efficient and some less efficient. But what feature of XOR do you want to mimic here and why?

Comment: @Tunaki That also holds if `a == 3 + Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `b == 5 + Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic the compactness, and that it is easy to see that the values have to be different

Comment: @spyr03 I don't know how you are using xor for booleans. You can replace `(a == true && b == false) || (a == false && b == true)` with `!(a ^ b)`, but `a != b` is simpler.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Why the `!`? It's exactly `a^b`. OP: the compactness of XOR stems from the fact that there are only two possible values. Therefore if a is different than b then it follows that one of them has the first value and the other has the second. But integers have a wider range. You need to at least mention the two variables and the two values so with four operands you can't have any expression with less than three binary operators in any language.

Comment: @RealSkeptic You're right it is just `a^b`. Silly mistake. I'd still write `a!=b` as it's clearer. You are right that 3 operations is the best you could hope for but it could still be compact. E.g. In a language with set literals and where `=` is a value comparison you could do `if [a, b] = [3, 5]`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code and there is no simpler way. However, you can omit the brackets, because `&&` binds stronger than `||`. See [Java operator order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two equations:

> ```
> a + b = 8            
> a * b = 15
> ```

If you solve this equation system,
it turns out the only pairs of values that satisfy both equations are `(3, 5)` and `(5, 3)`.
You could use this to rewrite the complex boolean with arithmetic:

```
(a + b == 8 && a * b == 15)
```

So instead of 7 boolean conditions,
now you have 3 boolean conditions + 1 addition + 1 multiplication.
It's shorter to write, but it's too clever.
Better to keep your original.